# Script Login Linux 1

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

No me hace el "if" del echo "Cuenta bloqueada."

```js
clear

let numIntentos=3

while [ $numIntentos -gt 0 ]
do
  echo "Introduzca el nombre de usuario: "
  read usuario
  echo "Introduzca la password: "
  read -s password
  
  if [ $usuario="Kevin" ] && [ $password="1234567890" ];
  then
    echo "Te has logueado correctamente."
    break
  else
    echo "Nickname o Password fueron introducidos incorrectamente."
    numIntentos=$((numIntentos-1))
  fi
done
if [ $numIntentos=0 ];
then
echo "Cuenta bloqueada."
fi
```

Comment: elif creo que esta mal, lo correcto seria else if

Comment: Estoy desde el terminal de Linux, el bash.

Comment: que error te salta?

Comment: se lo traja pero no me dice nada

Comment: cambia el else if por un else

Comment: A que te refieres y como lo dejaria.

Comment: ok, perdona pero es que estoy muy oxidado en sh, pero arriba la variable numIntentos la estas inicializando varias veces

Comment: no esta inicializada a tres y luego hasta que sea numIntentos=0 y luego no hace nada es el de salia este ultimo

Comment: creo que solo la tienes que iniciar la variable una vez para que guarde el numero de intentos en dicha variable

Comment: pues entonces **numIntentos=0 ; numIntentos--** no le encuentro el sentido, inicializas a tres y se va guardando los intentos y cuando llege al tres  **elif [ $numIntentos=];** es cuando deveria de saltar el else if

Comment: Lo cambie a un bucle while pero me dice que el elemento fi es inesperado (Solucionado)

Comment: Ahora no me dice nada sigue tragandoselo .

Comment: voy a intentar ejecutarlo yo

Comment: Lee sobre [ask] y edita la pregunta para añadir más información: ¿qué es lo que debería hacer este script? ¿qué es lo que está haciendo ahora (cómo falla)? ¿Recibes algún error? ¿A qué te refieres con que se lo traga? ¿qué es lo que se traga? ¿cómo está fallando?

Comment: Vale me funciona pero ahora el problema esta en que no me cuenta los intentos y no entra en el "if" del echo "Cuenta bloqueada"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para empezar, en tu `while` cambia la condición `[ numIntentos -gt 0 ]` por `[ $numIntentos -gt 0 ]`

También, al disminuir tu variable `numIntentos`, utiliza la expansión aritmética dada por `((operacion))`, es decir, en lugar de

```
numIntentos=$numIntentos-1
```

utiliza

```
numIntentos=$((numIntentos-1))
```

Además de pasar

```
if [ $usuario="Kevin" ] && [ $password="123456789O" ];
```

Por esto

```
if [ $usuario = "Kevin" ] && [ $password = "123456789O" ]
```

Nota los espacios entre las igualdades.

También cambia la condicional `[ $numIntentos=0 ]` por `[ $numIntentos -eq 0 ]` en el último `if`.

Eso va a permitir que tu programa se ejecute.

Por último, como recomendación, para que no se espere hasta que llegue a que la variable `numIntentos` sea 0, pon un `break` debajo de `echo "Te has logueado correctamente."`

Además, para que la contraseña no sea visible al momento de escribirla, utiliza el parámetro `-s` del *built-in* `read`, es decir: `read -s password`.

Comment: Vale me funciona pero ahora el problema esta en que no me cuenta los intentos y no entra en el "if" del echo "Cuenta bloqueada"

Comment: Se me olvidó hacer esa observación, entra en el `else` porque además parece que escribiste mal la contraseña, aceptada. Tu escribiste "123456789O", es decir, termina con una letra "o" mayúscula, no con el número cero "0", cambia eso.

Comment: no lo escribi a proposito para que tenga una letra la contraseña, pero lo cambiare, ya cambiado

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta.

Comment: Por cierto, no hubieras cambiado tu pregunta. Déjala como estaba, para que más personas puedan ver el tema como lo tenías, sino mi respuesta ya no tiene sentido.

Comment: Gracias me sirvio, y intente ponerlo como estaba y no me dejo